# Is the Canvas2D ellipse() specification/implementation incorrect?

Tags: javascript, canvas, angle, ellipse

I've been playing around with how to render wireframe perspective-correct spheres using only canvas2d and ellipse math.
It's been fun, but I've soon come to realize that the `ellipse()` function has a very strange implementation with regards to the spec.

Indeed, the `ellipse` function takes 7 (or 8) arguments:

```
ellipse(x, y, radiusX, radiusY, rotation, startAngle, endAngle)
```

The `startAngle` is described as such:

> The angle at which the ellipse starts, measured clockwise from the positive x-axis and expressed in radians.

Given a parameter `0 <= t <= 2 * PI`, we can compute the position of the associated point on the ellipse like so:

```
let dx = radiusX * cos(t)
let dy = radiusY * sin(t)

let px = x + dx * cos(rotation) - dy * sin(rotation)
let py = y + dx * sin(rotation) + dy * cos(rotation)
```

And if we use `startAngle = t`, our ellipse will begin its arc at our point. But. **But**. `t` is **NOT** an angle, and definitely not the angle of our point from the x-axis of the ellipse. Apparently some people still call it the *eccentric angle*, but my point still stands.

[(See here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Standard_parametric_representation)

And indeed, if we try to make the arc of an ellipse start at a specific **angle**, we can see that the result is *not* what we expect, unless the ellipse is a circle (`radiusX = radiusY`) or `startAngle` is a multiple of `PI / 2`.

[Here is an interactive demo I've put up so that you can witness the strange default behaviour](https://acatalepsie.fr/static/ellipse/).

My claim is that the function *should always* behave like it does in the *corrected* case with the current specification.

Either that or change the spec to talk about parameters `t` for `startAngle` and `endAngle`, and **avoid** saying they are angles, because currently they definitely are not.

Does anyone know how this implementation/spec came to be, if anyone reported this before and if not where to lead such a discussion?
Any other insight appreciated!

I found this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149077/what-does-startangle-mean-in-an-html5-canvas-ellipse) but it's rather unsatisfactory as replies merely show *how* to correct the function, but don't discuss whether the spec or implementation should be corrected.

Comment: No time right now for an answer, but it might help to start by reading the specs: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-context-2d-ellipse It's pretty clear why they called it angles there. "the points at startAngle and endAngle along this circle's circumference, [...] are the start and end points respectively, and the arc is the path along the circumference of this ellipse from the start point to the end point" (though I see there is a typo where "circle's circumference" should be "ellipse's circumference", will fix tomorrow).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have indeed taken a look at the specs (and saw the typo!). I would argue that they still leave too much to interpretation, as:
1. there is no mention of *eccentric angle*, and the usual meaning of "angle" does not apply here.
2. "the points at startAngle and endAngle along this [ellipse]'s circumference" will only mean what it seems to intend to when the ellipse has a circumference of 2pi, which is almost always not the case. If the points were defined as "points with eccentric angles startAngle and endAngle", there would no longer be any ambiguity.

Comment: And if it is indeed the intended meaning, it looks like the MDN doc is incorrect and must be updated, although that's a different concern. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/ellipse

Comment: Actually I take back what I wrote above, the sentence "the points at startAngle and endAngle along this [ellipse]'s circumference" only makes sense when the ellipse is a (unit) circle (as it was written), and does not have the intended behaviour for ellipses that aren't circles. The point with eccentric angle (pi / 4) is definitely not at the position reached by advancing 1/8th along the circumference of an ellipse.

Comment: I think I see your point, and indeed the specs themselves may be broken here, because it still uses the prose from a long time ago where we only had `ctx.arc()`. I lacked time today, but I'll open a specs issue tomorrow so that it gets updated. However note that we can only change the wordings, but not the behavior.

Comment: I opened https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/8408 Once this is fixed, we'll see to update MDN docs too. However as I said, the behavior will not change, only the specs, and the description can.

Comment: Thank you! And I expected changing the wording would be the best course of action, it's still great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the specs *were* wrong here.

Thanks to your question, I did edit the [`ellipse` method](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-context-2d-ellipse) so that it uses the angle from the eccentric circle, as were already doing all the implementations, and I also fixed the MDN article so it talks about "eccentric angle" in both cases.

As a general rule, when you find a bug in the specs, triple check you're sure about it, then open an issue on the specs's github project (most specs link to their repo at the top of the document, WHATWG specs also have a "*File an issue about the selected text*" link at the bottom-right corner of the page). But if you're not confident, writing a question on StackOverflow just like you did is also welcome, at least to get a confirmation that you found a bug.